# In BigQuery, compute difference between two rows in group by

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery, sum, pivot

```
with
  my_stats as (
    select 24996 as competitionId, 17 as playerId, 'on' as onOff, 8 as fga, 4 as fgm, 0.50 as fgPct union all
    select 24996 as competitionId, 17 as playerId, 'off' as onOff, 5 as fga, 3 as fgm, 0.60 as fgPct union all
    select 24996 as competitionId, 24 as playerId, 'on' as onOff, 9 as fga, 6 as fgm, 0.67 as fgPct union all
    select 24996 as competitionId, 24 as playerId, 'off' as onOff, 3 as fga, 1 as fgm, 0.33 as fgPct union all
    select 24996 as competitionId, 27 as playerId, 'on' as onOff, 5 as fga, 4 as fgm, 0.8 as fgPct
  ),
  
  my_output as (
    select 24996 as competitionId, 17 as playerId, 'diff' as onOff, 3 as fga, 1 as fgm, -0.1 as fgPct union all
    select 24996 as competitionId, 24 as playerId, 'diff' as onOff, 6 as fga, 5 as fgm, 0.34 as fgPct
  )
  

select * from my_stats
select * from my_output
```

Here is a simple example to demonstrate the problem we are struggling with. We have the table `my_stats`, where the primary key is a combination of `competitionId, playerId, onOff`, and where the `onOff` column can only be 'on' or 'off'. For a single `competitionId, playerId` then  (for which there are two rows, one for 'on', one for 'off'), we would like to subtract the values (on - off) from all other columns.

Hopefully the `my_output` table makes clear what output we need for this. In the case of `playerId = 27`, since this player has no 'off' row, they can simply be dropped from the output since there are no calculations to make.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    competitionId,
    playerId,
    'diff' as onOff,
    sum(case when onOff = 'on' then fga   else - fga   end) fga,
    sum(case when onOff = 'on' then fgm   else - fgm   end) fga,
    sum(case when onOff = 'on' then fgpct else - fgpct end) fgpct
from my_stats
where onOff in ('on', 'off')
group by competitionId, playerId
having count(*) = 2
```

This groups data by competition and player, then the conditional `sum()`s compute the difference between "on" and "off" values for each column. The `having` clause filters out groups that do not have both records available.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution based on a self-join:

```
select
    t1.competitionId,
    t1.playerId,
    'diff' as onOff,
    t1.fga - t2.fga as fga,
    t1.fgm - t2.fgm as fgm,
    t1.fgpct - t2.fgpct as fgpct
from my_stats as t1
join my_stats as t2
  on t1.competitionId = t2.competitionId
 and t1.playerId = t2.playerId
where t1.onOff = 'on'
  and t2.onOff = 'off'
```

You should check which apporoach is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT competitionId, playerId, 'diff' AS onOff,
  SUM(onOffSign * fga) AS fga,
  SUM(onOffSign * fgm) AS fgm,
  SUM(onOffSign * fgPct) AS fgPct  
FROM my_stats, 
  UNNEST([IF(onOff = 'on', 1, -1)]) onOffSign
GROUP BY competitionId, playerId
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
```